# How can I use LINQ to MySQL in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, unity-game-engine

I am making project in Unity3D using MySQL server. How can I make SQL-queries using LINQ? Because Unity3D working with .net 2.0 there is no way to use EntityFramework or smth like that, so I am have to type SQL-query by myself like that:

```
    var command =
        "INSERT INTO `person` (`surname`, `name`, `patronymic`, `login`, `password`, `category`, `organization`, `city`) VALUES ('" +
        surname +
        "','" + name + "','" + patronymic + "','" + login + "', '" + encrpass + "','" + category + "','" +
        organization + "','" + city + "');";

    try
    {
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, Connection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Whether there is a more simple way to use MySQL from Unity? 
Thanks.

Comment: If you can't use EF, how do you expect to use LINQ? In any case, you should *NEVER* concatenate values. Use parameterized queries

Comment: Do not use MySQL directly from your app. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38530543/3785314) explains why and the other option

Comment: @Programmer, this app will work only in office local network, so I`m not caring at all about security.

Comment: @Programmer the linked question doesn't explain anything related to *this* question.

Comment: Dapper.NET works on Mono, as [explained in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934757/does-dapper-work-on-mono)

Comment: Unity is using Mono, which *does* support LINQ. .NET 3.5 is actually 2.0 with extra libraries anyway.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My comment is saying that OP needs to do this in another way instead of the current way or the linq way for security reasons. My comment and the linked answer would still be valid but OP said this is only in-house app which makes it fine. That answer would have been useful if this program will be released on app store.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [LinqToDb](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db). It also has a version for Mono and it should work with Unity3D.

Good luck.

Comment: It can`t work with Unity because it`s using .NET 2.0, not 3.5.

Comment: Unity is using *Mono* and you *can* use LINQ. You aren't asking about LINQ though, you are asking about specific LINQ providers. LINQ is *only* the query language, not the provider that converts it to SQL

Answer (score 0):

For using LINQ in Unity you can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871230/how-do-i-use-linq-in-monodevelop-2-0-on-os-x/875704#875704) and see if it helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. In any case, the OP isn't asking about LINQ the language, but LINQ to an ORM.

Comment: You are right, but OP doesn't even know that Unity can work with .NET 3.5, maybe he needs to start checking from there.